# Bounds always zero with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, key-value-observing

I am trying to update my view when its bounds change. My view is laid out using Auto Layout in its superview.

Here is my code for observing bounds:

```
public override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "bounds", options: .New, context: nil)
    }

    public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        NSLog("[SkewedSplitView]: observer: %fx%f, %f:%f", self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height, self.bounds.origin.x, self.bounds.origin.y)
    }
```

Output:

> 2014-12-02 12:35:35.018 XXX[7365:2001261] [SkewedSplitView]: observer:
>   0.000000x0.000000, 0.000000:0.000000

I tried even Swits observers:

```
override public var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            NSLog("[SkewedSplitView]: bounds: %fx%f, %f:%f", self.frame.width, self.frame.height, self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y)
        }
    }
```

Output:

> 2014-12-02 12:35:35.012 XXX[7365:2001261] [SkewedSplitView]: bounds:
>   0.000000x0.000000, 0.000000:0.000000

Both were called just once.
Heres my code that lays out the view (using Cartography):

```
        let betters = SkewedSplitView()
        betters.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        self.addSubview(betters)

        constrain(betters, friends) { (betters, friends) in
            betters.bottom == friends.top - 3
            betters.leading == betters^.leading
            betters.trailing == betters^.trailing
            betters.height == 40
        }
```

On screen the view is laid out just fine, has correct frame.

Answer (score 1):

When using autolayout, bounds are not established when init is called. You may use ViewDidLayoutSubviews or ViewDidAppear. Place your NSLog in any of those and you will get bounds different from zero.
Regards